# android studio suddenly failed to resolve the dependencies about other modules

Tags: android, intellij-idea

for exmaple:

> ```
> compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$rootProject.ext.retrofitVersion"
> compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$rootProject.ext.retrofitVersion"
> compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:$rootProject.ext.retrofitVersion"
> ```

It supposed to be good, but I don't know what happened when I configured kotlin support in my android studio 3.0 preview canary 9 version.  When I stash the project my app module cannot resolve other modules which contains some gradle dependencies

Maybe the compiler has got a problem because I can still run my project successfully using ctrl+F10
[code used to be correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTpU7.jpg)

> ```
> rxlifecycleVersion = "1.0" as String
> retrofitVersion = "2.1.0" as String
> rxbindingVer = "1.0.0" as String
> ```

It seems that I can only checkout a new project from my remote repository. Any  idea how to solve this strange problem?

Comment: Have you tried to clean the project first?

Comment: yes,I tried it at first time,but it doesn't works

Comment: Could you show me the Log Info?

Comment: it just the editor show me the error high light and I could not found any error log in my logcat or event log window